# SQLite in Mac OS programming

Tags: database, macos, cocoa, sqlite

I'm new with Mac OS programming and facing problem to integrate SQLite database in my mac os project.

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "select * from MyTable";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSLog(@"sqlite3_step(selectstmt)=%d",sqlite3_step(selectstmt));
            NSLog(@"SQLITE_ROW= %d",SQLITE_ROW);

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger PrimaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                DatabaseInfo *databaseObj = [[DatabaseInfo alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:PrimaryKey];
                databaseObj.item1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                databaseObj.item2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];


                [appDelegate.mutablearray_Database addObject:databaseObj];

                [databaseObj release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

In the above methods controller never entered in while loop.That is why I'm not able to fetch data from database.

Can any one help me?

Please suggest me any sample code for SQLite Database implementation with Mac OS programming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to point out that it is probably best to either make use of CoreData ( apple's own implementation of sqlite, very powerful and efficient, though you will have to read some docs before you can wrap your head around the classes ) or [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which is a very well tested Objective-C wrapper for SQLite, [FMDB on github](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Second, how many rows are avaliable in your table? Since that NSLog is also calling sqlite3_step() it might just step over the only row you actually have.. the rest implementation roughly looks like what I am doing in some older projects of mine, for example:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
{
     while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
     {
          // get column data..
     }
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Comment: +1 for using FMDB. Also, I suggest OP sets a breakpoint to get a better sense of what's happening.

Comment: Another wrapper I wrote is located here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite

It has classes for accessing SQLite in a more traditional database way that I feel makes things easier.